# K-Means Text Clustering in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, k-means

How to implement K-Means Text Clustering in Tensorflow using `tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering`

- Currently it is working for `float` value but I need the solution for `text`
- if hw-data.txt contains float values it is working, if hw-data.txt contains text it is not working.

### Code:

```
hw_frame = pd.read_csv('./hw-data.txt', delim_whitespace=True,header=None, 
names=['Index', 'Height'])
hw_frame.drop('Index', 1, inplace=True)
print (hw_frame.head(5))

def input_fn():
  return tf.constant(hw_frame.as_matrix(), tf.float32, hw_frame.shape), None


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
kmeans = tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=2, 
relative_tolerance=0.0001)
_ = kmeans.fit(input_fn=input_fn)

clusters = kmeans.clusters()
print(clusters)
assignments = list(kmeans.predict_cluster_idx(input_fn=input_fn))
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty vaguely formulated without some actual example of inputs attached to it, but i'll take a stab.

K-means is a clustering method for objects, which means that in order for clusters to be formed, some meaningful "distance" metric needs to be established between distinct objects. Float "objects" can establish a distance by substraction : take the absolute of the difference and that's the distance. Strings unfortunately cannot be substracted meaningfully.

But all is not lost, alas. Enter word embeddings to the rescue, which can meaningfully embed a word (string) to a vector of numbers, so that alike words will have alike vectors. Also, vectors of the same dimension (length) can be meaningfully compared to extract a distance metric.

So i guess what you'd need to do is get a pretrained word2vec model from the web and put your words through it, then plug those into the csv. Alternately you could train one yourself, but unless you have a really large ammount of data (clean data mind you) i wouldn't bother with that alternative

Best of luck